# how to overcome on unresponsiveness of buttons using Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

Buttons in my application using Phonegap + Eclipse sometimes don't respond to the onclick event, making the App looks like it's frozen.

If I scroll the page up and down, sometimes they start working, but this can be accepted as a solution to the problem.

I've updated Cordova to version 2.7.0 but I still have the same issue.

Could anyone please help me on this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do much in Click handlers.

It freezes because the main thread is blocked by the click handler. Then everything stops. Do as much as you can on the server.

Comment: is there any possibility to use TAP event instead of CLICK or anyother so that it can resolve the issue

Comment: What would that change? The problem seems to be a time intensive operation in the event handler. When the event occurs it takes some time to run the function handling it.
You should look for a profiler for phonegap applications to find the code which takes so long.

Comment: yes the problem is with cordova bcoz in case of android it taking time of 300ms between touch and clickevent fire

Answer (score 0):

I use this [NoClickDelay](https://github.com/mmastrac/jquery-noclickdelay)

I did end up making some changes to it so that the touch and move worked better. I was finding that if your finger moved even the slightest it did not register the click. I increased the tolerance and it worked fine.

something like

```
if (Math.abs(e.changedTouches[0].screenX - this.startX) < 30 &&    Math.abs(e.changedTouches[0].screenY - this.startY) < 30 ) {
            this.theCallBack();
        }
```

Comment: this is for IOS is there any plugin for android pls mention reference

Comment: It is javascript so I use the same one in both android and iOS. I think it was designed primarily to get rid of the 300ms click delay in iOS but it works in android as well.